# ubuntu dropped my files to trash and don't restore

Tags: restore, trash

Ubuntu 14.04
Samsung SSD

I had a small amount of free space on PC.
I worked and saw, that my tools had strange behaviour, so I restarted tool.
But then I saw that the system also had strange behaviour, so I restarted Ubuntu.
After that I saw that my folder "Work" is empty (and it was terrifyingly).
Then I see that Work is inside ~/.local/share/Trash/files/Work.
I tried to restore (Restore menu item, when click right button), but Ubuntu said that it is not enough space.
I freed space and tried again.
Ubuntu said "Элементы в корзине не могут быть изменены". It translates like "Elements in trash could not be changed".

What can I do?

Comment: I created folder Work2 and run copy. It copied a half approximately, and space is finished again. But Ubuntu copied files in Work folder, not in Work2. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Next part. I connected additional hard drive disk and tried to copy data to it. Nothing happens. I deleted some files from external disk, and now can see it in my Trash (of PC). When I tried to delete them permanently OS shows me "File is not found"